# Rails what is the best solution to set sort param?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am for the moment setting the sort (order) params with Jquery and option tag.

My Jquery:

```
$("#sort").change(function() {
  window.location.search = "?sort=" + $(this).val();
});
```

My HTML/Rails view:

```
<p>order after: </p><%= select_tag("sort", options_for_select([['highest rating', 'rating'], ['highest value', 'vaerdi']], params[:sort]), :style => 'color:#666666;font-size:11px;') %>
```

The problem with the code it replace all the params. Example if the params is `?view=list` then it would overwrite it. Instead of adding the param sort: `?view=list&sort=rating`

Answer (score 0):

I did use jQuery param();

```
$("#sort").change(function() {
  window.location.search = jQuery.param({ sort: $(this).val(), view: '<%= escape_javascript(params[:view]) %>'});
});
```